# ¿Problema al obtener los valores en una función externa?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Bueno resulta que estoy tratando de obtener los valores que se encuentran en un txt, sucede que logro abrir el archivo, luego puedo leer linea a linea el txt, puedo separar los los valores y convertirlos en números, el problema ocurre cuando intento  obtener esos valores desde un script externo.

Estoy utilizando nodejs, uso el modulo de readline para obtener las lineas del txt, luego exporto esa función y desde otro archivo js la importo e intento obtener los valores que mencione anteriormente.

Acá están los códigos de ambos archivos. En este leo el txt linea a linea y luego convierte sus valores a números.

```
function ReadData() {
const readFile = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('./grafico.txt'),
    output: process.stdout,
    console: false,
});
readFile.on('line', function (line) {
    element = line.split('\t');
    for (let property of element) {
        convertNumber = parseFloat(property);
        // convertNumber;
    }
})
```

}

Y desde otro archivo utilizo esta linea de codigo para ejecutarlo, pero al imprimir su valor es undefined

```
conexionHidro.ReadData();
```

No se que hacer, por favor alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Si tienes la función en un archivo y la tratas de usar en otro, entonces me parece debes exportar dicha función

Comment: si, la funcion la exporte, pero igual sigue recibiendo undefined

Comment: Agrega por favor como la estas exportando por favor

Comment: primero creo un objeto `const data = {}` y luego  añado la funcion al objeto `data.ReadData = ReadData;` y por ultimo la exporto `module.exports = data;`

Comment: La función `ReadData` no retorna nada ni se almacena algo.

Comment: No, intente retornar `element = line.split('\t');` pero no funciono, tambien intente almacenarla pero al consultarla desde el otro archivo sigue siendo undefined

Comment: Necesitamos ver un poco mas de tu codigo, con los cambios que te han sugerido. Como lo estas invocando ?. Otro detalle que veo es en la parte de ```console: false``` en la documentación no veo nada sobre ese parámetro.